# How to make an array of all the elements that are in all of arbitrary number of arrays in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to solve this question using .filter method or other higher-order function, but cannot find an answer.

This is what I made so far, but it only compares first and second arguments.

```
function intersection() {
   for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      return arguments[i].filter((x) => arguments[i + 1].includes(x) === true);
    }
   }
```

Comment: An unconditional return statement in a loop doesn't make sense. The loop will always iterate once.

Comment: try to first write a function that finds the intersection of only 2 arrays. Once you have that, [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is your friend to extend it to an arbitrary number of arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way of doing it:

```js
const data=[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],[3,6,9,12,15],[2,4,6,8,10,12],[6,12,18,24]];

function intersection (dat){  
  return dat.reduce((a,c)=>
    a.filter((e)=>c.includes(e)));
}

console.log(intersection(data));
```

All arrays that need to be tested are combined in an overarching array `dat`. The filtering in the `reduce()` loop will be done cumulatively over all subarrays starting with the first subarray.

Comment: Thank you! I wrote like below by following your advice, but still returns error...

     function intersection(array) {
       const dat = [array];
       return dat.reduce((prev, current) => {
         return prev.filter((x) => current.includes(x) === true);
       });
     }

Comment: I changed my snippet into a function. Please check again.